# How to export XML of webpart on the page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-part, powershell

I want to export the Web part XML based on GUID to the local. I am trying to export from SharePoint 2013 using CSOM PowerShell. Anyone suggest on this?

```
function EnsureDirectory($exportFolderPath)
{
  if ( -not (Test-Path $exportFolderPath) ) {New-Item $exportFolderPath -Type Directory | Out-Null}
}
 
function ExportAllWebParts()
{
  $WebURL= ""
  $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($WebURL)
  $Page = $ctx.web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("")  
  $ctx.Load($Page)  
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  $wpManager = $Page.GetLimitedWebPartManager([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
  $webparts = $wpManager.Webparts  
  $ctx.Load($webparts)  
   $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

   if($webparts.Count -gt 0){  
    Write-Host "Looping through all webparts"  
    foreach($webpart in $webparts){
        $exportPath = "" + "\" + $webpart.Title + ".xml"
        $xwTmp = new-object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($exportPath,$null);
        $xwTmp.Formatting = 1;#Indent
        $wpManager.ExportWebPart($webpart, $xwTmp);
        $xwTmp.Flush();
        $xwTmp.Close();

        #$webpartXmlWriter = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($fileName,$null)
        #$webpartXmlWriter.Formatting = [System.Xml.Formatting]::Indented
        #$wpManager.ExportWebPart($webpart,$webpartXmlWriter)
          
        
        }  
              
    }  
}
ExportAllWebParts
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below PowerShell code:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
function EnsureDirectory($exportFolderPath)
{
  if ( -not (Test-Path $exportFolderPath) ) {New-Item $exportFolderPath -Type Directory | Out-Null}
}
 
function ExportAllWebParts($siteUrl,$pageUrl,$exportFolderPath)
{
  $web = Get-SPWeb $siteUrl
  $wpm = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($pageUrl, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
 
 EnsureDirectory $exportFolderPath
 
foreach($wp in $wpm.WebParts)
{
  $wp.ExportMode="All";
  $exportPath = $exportFolderPath + "\" + $wp.Title + ".xml"
  $xwTmp = new-object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($exportPath,$null);
  $xwTmp.Formatting = 1;#Indent
  $wpm.ExportWebPart($wp, $xwTmp);
  $xwTmp.Flush();
  $xwTmp.Close();
}
```

Inside `foreach` you can add one more condition to check the GUID of web-part and then you can export your web-part once condition fulfilled.

**Source**: [Export web parts to XML using PowerShell](https://radutut.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/export-web-parts-to-xml-using-powershell/)

**Alternate solution**:

Alternatively you can also use PnP PowerShell to return the web part XML of a web part registered on a site as given in below example:

```
Get-PnPWebPartXml -ServerRelativePageUrl "/sites/demo/sitepages/home.aspx" -Identity a2875399-d6ff-43a0-96da-be6ae5875f82
```

**Source**: [Get-PnPWebPartXml](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpwebpartxml)

Comment: due to some constraint pnp we cant use it. But can i get this with CSOM.. I think that could be really good to me.

Comment: Yes, check above CSOM code. with some minor changes you can achieve what you want. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: annot find an overload for "ExportWebpart" and the argument count: "2".
At C:\:24 char:9
+         $wpManager.ExportWebPart($webpart, $xwTmp);
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: I am getting above error. find the updated code